# How do I vertically align and customize slider arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have add css to stylize the previous and next arrows for `.customer-logos` , however the standard button style still shows under the added css? How do I fix this issue and align the buttons to be on either side of the slider not above and below?

https://jsfiddle.net/huten0wq/46/

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: FontAwesome; font-size: 40px; line-height: 1; color: gray; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }   

.slick-prev:before { content: "\f053"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before { content: "\f054"; }

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next { left: -10px; top: 70px; right: auto; }
.slick-next:before { content: "\f054"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before { content: "\f053"; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want probably

```
.customer-logos button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(3) {
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful and resolves my alignment issue thank you! How do I style the buttons without the "standard" button still being visible underneath?

Comment: under .customer-logos button you can add background-color border radius padding .etc. but make sure if you add padding change the top from 50 to your needs so it centers, checkout the one i customized here
http://codepen.io/muratkh/pen/NdOeQO